# Running aggregations on case insensitive keywords elasticsearch 5.1

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I am trying to run aggregations on some keywords in my index but I want to lowercase all the keywords while indexing and searching but elastic 5.1 does not support normalizer. Also, I don't want to index them as text and enable fielddata. What are other options to accomplish this?

Comment: You know, fielddata is not that bad in all cases. If your nodes allows for extra memory usage from fielddata, why not?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I think elastic doesn't recommend using it that's why I am sceptic.

Comment: Correct, we don't recommend using it because most of the times it doesn't make sense to aggregate on analyzed fields. But this doesn't come from a bad design or a bug, for example, it's just an improvement to memory usage. But, if your memory usage is fine and you don't have other choice, use it.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiStefan. Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an analyzer made of the `keyword` tokenizer and `lowercase` token filter.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_keyword": { 
          "type":      "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "standard", 
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type":     "text",
              "analyzer": "my_keyword" 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't apply analyzer on keywords right? Also can't run aggregations on text.

Comment: Ok, the other option is to lowercase your data before sending it to ES. Or upgrade to 5.3

Comment: just lowercase the data before sending it. I dont see the difficulty in this. you have to reindex anyway

Comment: For now I am using fielddata but will lowercase all these fields before deploying to prod.